# Is it possible to bind an ivar with no property declaration?

Tags: .net, objective-c, xamarin.ios, interop

If there is a public ivar in an objective c class such as

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    NSString *thisItem;
}
```

Is there any way to add that ivar to my objective c bindings so I can access it in C# without changing the class and adding a property declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible? sure, if you can do it in C or Objective-C then you can do it using .NET too.

In this case you can p/invoke into [`object_getInstanceVariable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/object_getInstanceVariable) and other ObjC runtime functions. However this won't produce code that is easy to maintain.